# Eval in replacing and resolving variables inside a PHP string

Tags: php, eval

```
$html = '<html><body>$DATA</body></html>';

$DATA = "<h1>Hi</h1>";

eval("\$html = \"$html\";");
echo $html;
```

The above piece of code will resolve the variable of $DATA properly. While

```
$html = '<html><body>$DATA</body></html>';

$DATA = "<h1>Hi</h1>";

$html = "$html";

echo $html;
```

This piece of code will not. Why? What is the difference between these two?

Isn't the `eval("\$html = \"$html\";");` equal to just `$html = "$html";` ?

Why first one works while the other one doesn't?

---

As in my above examples; `$DATA` is and must be defined after the `$html`. That's the case :). In other case I wouldn't even have a question and bother.

But it's... why first one works while second one doesn't. And how to make the second one works? But primarly why it doesn't in fact work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case `$DATA` inside `$html` is evaluated during the `eval()`, and at this point `$DATA` is defined (because, defined before `eval()`).

In the second case, `$DATA` is interpolated on this line `$html = '<html><body>$DATA</body></html>';` and at this point `$DATA` is undefined.

```
$DATA = "<h1>Hi</h1>";
$html = "<html><body>$DATA</body></html>";
```

The code above works because `$DATA` is defined before the evaluation.

As @NigelRen pointed out, in the second case, the string use single quotes and variable won't be interpolated inside "single-quoted" strings.

Comment: But it's not what my question meant, mmmmm, `$DATA` is and must be defined after the `$html`

Comment: But isn't the `eval("\$html = \"$html\";");` equal to `$html = "$html";` ?

Comment: @krystian2160 No. This is not equal. In the case of eval, `$html` is evaluated, but in `$html = "$html";`, the `$html` is not evaluated and is equal to `$html=$html;` so, nothing changed.